# query to get latest from many to many join table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables. Stocks have many News articles and News articles can refer to 1 or more Stocks. This is modelled with a Stock table, a News table and a Stock_News table.

How would I get the latest News article for say 30 stock symbols I provide?  What indices would make this most efficient?

My News table has `id`, `link`, `published_at`. (index on published_at, id primary key)

My Stocks table has `id`, `symbol`. (index on symbol, id primary key)

My stock_news table has `stock_id` `news_id`. (index on each individually and combined)

Currently I am using but i as wondering if this is the best way

```
SELECT n.link, s.symbol, n.published_at FROM news n 
JOIN stock_news sn on n.id = sn.news_id 
JOIN stocks s on s.id = sn.stock_id where s.symbol in ('AAPL', 'GOOG' ... etc) 
ORDER BY n.published_at DESC;
```

The EXPLAIN query on some demo data shows:

```
 Sort  (cost=8.92..8.92 rows=1 width=115)
   Sort Key: n.published_at DESC
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.50..8.92 rows=1 width=115)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.45..7.51 rows=1 width=12)
               Hash Cond: (s.id = sn.stock_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on stocks s  (cost=0.00..4.05 rows=2 width=12)
                     Filter: ((symbol)::text = ANY ('{AAPL,GOOG}'::text[]))
               ->  Hash  (cost=2.67..2.67 rows=223 width=16)
                     ->  Seq Scan on stock_news sn  (cost=0.00..2.67 rows=223 width=16)
         ->  Index Scan using news_pkey on news n  (cost=0.05..1.40 rows=1 width=119)
               Index Cond: (id = sn.news_id)
```

Comment: looks good, but you might want to check out the code review forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.symbol) n.link, s.symbol, n.published_at
FROM news n JOIN
     stock_news sn
     ON n.id = sn.news_id JOIN
     stocks s
     ON s.id = sn.stock_id 
WHERE s.symbol IN ('AAPL', 'GOOG' ... etc) 
ORDER BY s.symbol, n.published_at DESC;
```

For performance you want indexes on:  `stocks(symbol, id)`, `stock_news(stock_id, new_id)`, and `news(id)`.

Comment: Yep, +1, except that SQL looks funny to me :)

Comment: why not an index on `news(published_at)`? Also, when you say `stocks(symbol,id)` is that a multicolumn index or 2 separate indices?

Comment: @TerenceChow . . .  `published_at` is the second key in the `order by`.  An index is useful for that.